# Simple regex matches online debuggers but not when run by PHP 7.3

Tags: php, regex, pcre

my regex runs on Debuggex and shows a match but when run in PHP it does not match.
This regex is not made by me because I'm simply not compatible with regex and that's why I can't debug it now (2 hours already).

Please help!

Expression:  `^0+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+0+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+0+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+[0\-1]+0`

String to match:`0111111101111011011110000`

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/suYEnbej7gGSCH9O) - matches.

PHP version is 7.3. Tried both on Windows and Linux PHP environments.

The expression was written for PHP 5.6. I am aware than with PHP 7 and up, they updated the PCRE engine, so that's probably the reason why my regex does not work.

Please help!

Comment: PHP hasn't changed how regex works though. If they did, there would be some serious backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: Jeto, I was about to get happy but it does not: https://3v4l.org/FTSfL

Comment: see the problem here https://regex101.com/r/UNqz9D/1/debugger

Comment: What is your pattern supposed to match?

Comment: For a 25bits number: `^(?>0[01]{7}){3}0`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte This, it should match this: `0111111101111011011110000`. The pattern is being generated in a previous part of the code and it's different for different use cases. The practical situation of the pattern and the expressions shows it should match this one. I'm 99% sure the problem is in the pattern, as we speak here I'm still debugging and trying different stuff. As I said, regex is not my thing and I'm struggling.

Comment: @ZahariTenev: and what are the characteristics of *"this"*?

Comment: It's a part of a 1200-characters string which is being divided to 120 slots, 10 characters each. The zeroes and ones indicate blank spaces in a virtual "box". The pattern is supposed to check if we have enough blank spaces for the specified item (which is "this" - the string). It's waay more specific if I need to explain the whole thing. I thought the regex can be edited to become "fixed" easily by someone with higher skill than me.

Comment: The problem is that the original pattern is a *pathological pattern*, that means there are to much steps to make it fail or succeed. (that's why `preg_match` returns `false` and not 0 or 1). You can use `preg_last_error` to have confirmation. The problem has nothing to do wiht the php version, but probably with the backtracking limit set in the php.ini. Whatever you have to change this pattern.

Comment: 1. If you need to match hyphens move them to the end of the character class,`[01-]`. 2. Simplify it so that each subsequent pattern does not  match at the same location

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" my problem by increasing `pcre.backtrack_limit` in `php.ini`.

I know it doesn't really fix the badly written regex, it's more like using duct tape to attach a broken chair leg. 
But currently, I don't have the time to rewrite the regex having in mind regular expressions aren't my thing.

Thanks to everyone for your ideas and intentions to help me.